# Замена данных в одной таблице из другой при совпадении столбцов

Tags: sqlite

Есть две таблицы с данными:

*tblUsers:* login, hash, pass

*tblPassHash:* pass, hash

Необходимо в поле **tblUsers.pass** первой таблицы (сейчас оно пустое) подставить значение **tblPassHash.pass** (из второй, соответствующего поля), при условии, что `hash` из первой = `hash` из второй

Пожалуйста, подскажите как

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
UPDATE 
  tblUsers t1,
  tblPassHash t2
SET 
  t1.pass = t2.pass
WHERE
  t1.hash = t2.hash
```

Не уверен, работает ли первый вариант конкретно в sqlite. Если нет, точно сработает второй, менее красивый:

```
UPDATE 
  tblUsers
SET
  pass = (
    SELECT tblPassHash.pass
    FROM tblPassHash
    WHERE tblPassHash.hash = tblUsers.hash
  )
```

Comment: В обоих примерах ругается на алиасы (псевдонимы) таблиц =(

Comment: попробуйте убрать или переименовать алиасы, и заменить их в обращениях. И как ругается, что пишет?

Comment: Теперь в первом случае ругается на запятую при перечислении таблиц после UPDATE. Во втором случае без ошибок отработало вот так

UPDATE tblUsers
SET pass = (
 SELECT tblPassHash.pass
 FROM tblPassHash
 WHERE tblPassHash.hash = tblUsers.hash
)

Comment: Огромное спасибо за помощь! Теперь вникнуть бы, а то я уже про джоины в update начал прогугливать

Comment: Во время апдейта строчки в первой таблицы выбирается нужное значение из второй)

Comment: Вопрос насколько это затратно. Если я правильно понимаю - для каждой записи будет выполняться отдельный подзапрос. Поэтому я и подумал про джоины и возможную оптимизацию